# Android JSON Error NullPointing

Tags: php, android, json

I'm using JSON for get all the questions in sql..

I have used that same logic for get other data...

But, when i try to Log my JSON Object or Print it.. I got an NullPointException...

```
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJson("http://10.0.2.2/qm/perguntas.php", "GET", params);
    Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());
```

And the php code:

```
    <?php
    $response = array();
    require_once 'include/DB_Connect.php';
    $db = new DB_Connect();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM perguntas") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $response["perguntas"] = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $pergunta = array();
                $pergunta["uid"] = $row["uid"];
                $pergunta["pergunta"] = $row["pergunta"];
                $pergunta["remetente"] = $row["remetente"];
                $pergunta["para"] = $row["para"];
                $pergunta["anonimo"] = $row["anonimo"];
                //$pergunta["resposta"] = $row["resposta"];
                array_push($response["perguntas"], $pergunta);
        }
    $response["success"] = 1;
    echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Sem perguntas";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Have you checked that the URL `http://10.0.2.2/qm/perguntas.php` works  before testing it in the code? Try with a **CTRL + Left mouse click** and check if the results are fetched outside the code too (This will open a Web Browser tab within Eclipse). I see nothing wrong with it thus far. Neither with the PHP script, nor the Android code.

Comment: More context is required what type is jsonParser?